# Python equivalent of db.collection.explain()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, metadata

I am trying to find a way to obtain metadata about a database or of a mongodb collection and I would like to do it with python.

In the mongo shell the command is this:

`db.collection.explain()`

When I run the program I get the following error message:

`TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'explain' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

However I have not been able to identify an equivalent command in pymongo.

Comment: What do you mean by "metadata"?

Comment: With the explain Method I can get more Information about a Collection. More information about the thing itself is metadata

Comment: Again, what kind of information? The indexes on this collection? The size? Number of documents? Granted privileges on this collection?

Comment: Maybe `db.getCollectionInfos({"name" : "collection"})`? But I have no clue how to invoke it from python.

Comment: I want to have all the information that belongs to the technical metadata. So the 4 examples you listed would interest me among others.

Comment: db.collection.find().explain()

Comment: @prasad_ this shows the execution plan of the query but not the "collection metadata"

Comment: The following shell commands get the collection and database level 'meta data', respectively: `db.collection.stats()` and `db.stats()`.